# How many are the positive integer pairs

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many are the positive integer pairs $ (p, n) $, $ p $ prime, such that:

$ p ^ 2 = [(2 ^ n + 1) ^ 5-1] / 2^n $

**Solution:** RHS is equal to $2^{4n}+5\cdot2^{3n}+10\cdot2^{2n}+10\cdot2^n+5$ which is $5$ mod $8$ for $n\geq3.$ However, $5$ is not a valid quadratic residue mod $8,$ so we must have $n=1,2$ which gives $p^2=121,781,$ and only the former is a perfect square. Thus the only such pair is $(p,n)=(11,1)$

Is there another approach to this question? some more deductive

Comment: What do you consider "more deductive"? This approach is quite straightforward (and suggested by the setup). Note: You can in fact show that for $n = 2$, the expression is $ 5 \pmod{8}$ already, because of the $10 \cdot 2^n$ term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We expand the right-hand side:
$$  \frac{(2^n+1)^5-1}{2^n} = 2^{4n} + 5\cdot 2^{3n} + 10\cdot 2^{2n} + 10 \cdot 2^n + 5  \text{.}  $$
This is clearly odd, so the left-hand side cannot be even, so no solution has $p = 2$ and we may assume $p$ is odd.  Let $p = 2k+1$ with $k \geq 1$ and expand
$$  p^2 = (2k+1)^2 = 4k^2 + 4k + 1  \text{.}  $$
We can manipulate: \begin{align*}
4k^2 + 4k + 1 &= 2^{4n} + 5\cdot 2^{3n} + 10\cdot 2^{2n} + 10 \cdot 2^n + 5  \\
4k^2 + 4k &= 2^{4n} + 5\cdot 2^{3n} + 10\cdot 2^{2n} + 10 \cdot 2^n + 4  \\
k(k+1) &= 2^{4n-2} + 5\cdot 2^{3n-2} + 5\cdot 2^{2n-1} + 5 \cdot 2^{n-1} + 1  \text{.}
\end{align*}
The left-hand side is the product of two consecutive positive integers, so is even.  The right-hand side is odd if $n > 1$, so any solution must have $n \leq 1$.  Since $n$ is given positive, we try $n = 1$ and obtain the only solution, $k(k+1) = 30$, so $k = 5$ (or $k = -6$, but that does not lead to positive $p$).  So $p = 2(5)+1 =11$ and we obtain the same solution you did.